# How to insert tracking JS code (snippet) into Piwigo gallery?

Tags: javascript

Javascript code for tracking which was incorporated into Joomla installation through a Custom HTML module has no effect on Piwigo gallery. How visits to the gallery could be tracked, i.e. where the code goes in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Piwigo is completely external to Joomla.  You will need to put the tracking code directly into Piwigo.  You may want to contact the Piwigo to check if they have a plugin for analytics.